# Исключить заголовок из the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress, content

Очередной вопрос от новичка: надо исключить в цикле вывода материалов заголовки из `the_content()`. Либо сделать их кликабельными по `the_permalink()`.
Наверно, было бы проще изначально выводить материалы в архиве через `the_excerpt()`. Но мне не нравится в нем потеря исходного форматирования, троеточие после анонса, фиксированная длина анонса и много чего еще. Конечно, все это можно допилить и кастомизовать, но едва ли будет проще и потребует куда больше знаний

Comment: Вы все заголовки в `the_content()` хотите сделать кликабельными что ли? А Вам не кажется странным выводить всю статью в анонсе? Я конечно не знаю насколько они длинные, но 10-20 статей в ряд с полным текстом, выглядит не супер юзабельно)

Comment: Да, все заголовки анонсов сделать кликабельными и настраиваемыми. Анонсы оборваны по more в нужных местах. Да, решение кажется странноватым, поскольку все настраивается вручную. Но и сайт маленький и ручной - авторский

Comment: Simon, по существу вопроса заголовка в content сможете посоветовать?

Comment: Ну, Ваш вопрос -- вилами по воде и я бы вообще не советовал такое делать. Можете попробовать добавить фильтр на `the_content` где будете либо удалять заголовки, либо оборачивать в ссылки. Только учитывайте чтобы это происходило в соответствии с Вашей задумкой (я не совсем понимаю в каких конкретно ситуациях), добавьте соответствующие проверки, чтобы это не было на single поста например или не знаю как Вы это выводите и где.

Comment: Решил пока попробовать обернуть в div, а далее в css

Comment: Так а что это даст? Раз оборачиваете в div, то можете и удалять точно так же и оборачивать в ссылку.

Comment: Либо если это div чтобы скрыть при помощи css, то можно это и без div сделать.

Comment: Вариант с классами css через оборачивание `the_content` показалось проще, чем через фильтр. Потому что более знакомо и, главное, работает